# Why is this TF-IDF sentiment analysis classifier performing so well?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, logistic-regression, tf-idf

[Jupter Notebook](https://github.com/DenJev/NLPAirline/blob/master/AirlinesNotebook.ipynb)

The last confusion matrix is for the test set. Is this a case of overfitting with logistic regression? Because even when not pre-processing the text much (including emoticons, punctuation) the accuracy is still very good. Good anyone give some help/advice?

Comment: A link to an external resource is fine for clarification or background, but your question here on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. Please at least summarize what's in the resource you link to. Some of us won't be able to open it even if we wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing the `TfidfVectorizer` on whole data before `train_test_split` which may be a reason for increased performance due to "data leakage". Since the `TfidfVectorizer` is learning the vocabulary on your whole data, it is:

- including words in vocabulary that are not present in train and only present in test (`out-of-bag` words)
- adjusting the `tf-idf` scores based on data from test words also

Try the following:

```
tweets_train, tweets_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reviews['text'].tolist(), 
                                                  reviews['airline_sentiment'], 
                                                  test_size=0.3, 
                                                  random_state=42)

X_train = v.fit_transform(tweets_train)
X_test = v.transform(tweets_test)
```

And then check the performance.

**Note**: This may not be the only reason for the performance. Or maybe the dataset is such that simple tf-idf works well for it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. The classification accuracy change very little. I assume this data is very easy to classify as you mention.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Tf-idf vectorizer does all the basic pre-processing

1. such as removing emoticons, punctuation,
2. converting alpha characters into lower case, etc.

Having set this, what @vivek Kumar mentioned is a valid point. Fitting the vectorizer on the complete data is not the right practice.

One key approach to cross check the performance metrics is to understand what model learning is right/wrong!

Look at model coefficients for input features (if its a linear model else [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap)).

Based on your github repo, When I tried to understand the Model co-eff this is what I got. It looks like bit of overfitting since words like `luggage`, `systems` were also given negative weights.

```
top_n,bottom_n = 15,15
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature_names':v.get_feature_names(),
                                'co_eff':clf.coef_[0]}) 
df=df.sort_values('co_eff',ascending=False).iloc[np.r_[0:top_n,-bottom_n:0]]
print(df)
```

output:

```
    feature_names   importn
606         thank  6.918280
607        thanks  6.269803
281         great  4.497794
74        awesome  4.366976
391          love  4.296043
84           best  3.864701
40        amazing  3.710287
213     excellent  2.749308
623           thx  2.695160
358         kudos  2.663612
279          good  2.618669
149          cool  2.582528
53     appreciate  2.399666
528          rock  2.222901
502         quick  2.020487
595        system -1.829668
643        trying -1.839126
80           bags -1.899045
394       luggage -1.957718
78            bag -1.968421
192          dont -2.060734
104          call -2.075544
532          rude -2.255443
308          hold -2.588171
316          hour -2.640191
110     cancelled -2.719347
445       nothing -2.743778
171       delayed -2.869854
704         worst -3.262978
317         hours -3.348654
```

P.S. : For sentiment analysis, this is not a performing so well range. Once you go for complex model / better text processing - results will improve a lot more.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Is there anything wrong with luggage being flagged as a negative term, if inherent to airline tweet datasets it is used in negative statements?

Comment: As such word luggage does not carry any negative emotion right.! May be many of the times, when people spoke about luggage they mentioned  bad experience.